# How to convert this Route to new react router style

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my project, I saw router v5.2.0 is installed and based on that, routes are defined on where all route are under the switch.  **I am working on update of `react-router` to latest version, so first I am converting all route with `CompactRoute`**

Here is My Current Route:

```
<Route
  path={
    '/' +
    Constants.USER_ADMIN_TYPE +
    '/show-details/:name/:showId'
  }
  render={(props) => (
    <Admin
      userType={Constants.USER_ADMIN_TYPE}
      comp={
        <ShowDetails
          {...props}
          userType={
            Constants.USER_ADMIN_TYPE
          }
        />
      }
    />
  )}
/>
```

I need help to convert this to latest `react-router` syntax.

I had tried, doing like this but its not rendering, and also I am confused, how can I pass the props in new router?

```
<CompatRoute
  path={
    '/' +
    Constants.USER_ADMIN_TYPE +
    '/show-details/:name/:showId'
  }
  component={
    <Admin
      userType={Constants.USER_ADMIN_TYPE}
      comp={
        <ShowDetails
          userType={
            Constants.USER_ADMIN_TYPE
          }
        />
      }
    />
  }
/>
```

Comment: What does "new react router style" mean? Are you upgrading from RRD v5 to v6? Have you followed or read though the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) guide, the [Main Concepts](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts), and/or the [FAQ](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq)? If you are upgrading to v6 then this `CompatRoute` custom route component likely won't work as you are maybe expecting.

Comment: i am following official guide to migrate to v6 one by one , with CompatRoute
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/8753

But didn't knwo how to write proper route for compatroute ,similar to my current working route for v5.2.0

Comment: I see. And are you at the step where `CompatRoute` is swapped to `Route` and the route `component` prop is swapped to `element`?

Comment: I had tried , to swap comp , with both component and element too , but nothing works till now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your `react-router-dom@5` route:

```
<Route
  path={'/' + Constants.USER_ADMIN_TYPE + '/show-details/:name/:showId'}
  render={(props) => (
    <Admin
      userType={Constants.USER_ADMIN_TYPE}
      comp={
        <ShowDetails
          {...props}
          userType={
            Constants.USER_ADMIN_TYPE
          }
        />
      }
    />
  )}
/>
```

To convert this to the `react-router-dom@6` APIs/syntax ensure the following:

1. Render all `Route` components within a [`Routes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes) component. The `Routes` component is the spiritual successor to, and replacement of, the RRDv5 `Switch` component. The `Routes` component is what does the heavy lifting of matching the current URL path to a route it manages.
2. Render all routed content on the `Route` component's single [`element`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#element) prop as a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. as JSX.
3. There are no longer "route props", i.e. the RRDv5 `history`, `location`, and `match` route props. These are all now accessed via React hooks: `location` via [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location), `params` via [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params), and instead of a history ***object*** there is now a `navigate` ***function*** via the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook.

The above route converted to RRDv6 route API/syntax:

```
<Routes>
  ... other routes ...
  <Route
    path={`/${Constants.USER_ADMIN_TYPE}/show-details/:name/:showId`}
    element={(
      <Admin
        userType={Constants.USER_ADMIN_TYPE}
        comp={<ShowDetails userType={Constants.USER_ADMIN_TYPE} />}
      />
    )}
  />
  ... other routes ...
</Routes>
```